# Unity3D and Tiled Four weeks of searching

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, tiled

I'm using Tiled and Tiled2Unity to make my maps the problem is i have made multiple layer in Tiled (image 1) all is good but when i import it in unity my prefabs are always behinde the the objects (layer 2) of the map i tried to change the Z index but nothing , after multiple tries i found that the sprite renderer is the problem (Image 2) when i create a simple cube with mesh renderer all work great (Image 2) please Help .

Image 1 :

[image]
Image 2 :

[image]

Comment: Reverse layer order? [check this](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/611596/how-do-you-change-a-sprites-sorting-layer-in-c.html)

Comment: no want the chicken to be above the barrels i change the z-index value but nothing

Comment: What type of object is the barrel?

Comment: The `z` value of transform is not the thing you need. You need to reverse order of your layers in Tiled so that Unity will sort them correctly during draw calls. You can either do that in tiled or in Unity by changing the sort order adding new sort layers in the settings. [Read this](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/2d-game-creation/sorting-layers)

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Use unity layer and sorting order to manage your sprites on right place. You can have look at unity documentation or find any tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to manage the sorting layer name or order on your layers via custom properties in Tiled. [See this link](http://www.seanba.com/megadadadventures.html).